Date Datatype mismatch problem in SSIS, they are different
enter image description here
I have a table in my database which is set to Date = date, Time = time(0).
I had trouble mapping on Lookup due to data type mismatch and I realised that when hovering my mouse over the destination column, it says datatype of my Date and Time are Unicode String DT_WSTR. Why is this happening and how do I fix it? I assume there is a problem with the way how I created the Date Dimension? But it should say the datatype is string if it is wrong. Is it okay to map my date and time using DT_WSTR?
Thank you
enter image description here

Please dont post screen shots and see here for how to ask a good question:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question
